# Get coordinate from psd

Tags: html, svg, photoshop, psd

I have a psd file with a path (path). How can I get the coordinates for the javascript animation along the path?

Exampl:
http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/8162640

Coordinates should look like this:

The path, coordinates you need to draw.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
  <path
      d="m 480,200 c 100,0 0,250 100,200 100,-50 0,-250 100,-300 100,-50 350,100 100,200 -250,100 -350,100 -600,0 -250,-100 0,-250
 100,-200 100,50 0,250 100,300 100,50 0,-200 100,-200"
      id="wiggle"
      class="weirdPath"/>
```

Track:
   http://zalil.su/8054040

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy the path out of the PSD (using the Path Selection tool) and paste it into Illustrator, you'll be able to save that path as an SVG file.

If you open the SVG file in your code editor, you should see an `svg` element that has a `path` element similar to the one you pasted.

Alternatively, if your path is the only thing on your artboard, you can pretty reliably "Export As" an SVG and get a similar result. I just like using Illustrator for SVG, it gives you a little bit more control.